# How to Color the "Overshoot" Background of an NSCollectionView

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit, nscollectionview

I have implemented a **collection view** on my Cocoa app following [Ray Wenderlich's tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/145978/nscollectionview-tutorial) (very helpful, given how buggy and broken Apple's API is in this area).

In the tutorial, the collection view's canvas is colored black using the following code (all code is in view controller class' `viewDidLoad()` method):

```
collectionView.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.black.cgColor
```

However, the area that "peeks" when you overshoot ("rubber-band") the scroll  using -for example- a magic mouse/scrollwheel, is still white and very distracting:

[image]

I'm trying to make the whole content area black. In my storyboard, I set the background color of both the `NSScrollView` and `NSClipView` that contain the collection view to black, but it doesn't change the appearance.
Also tried the programmatic alternative: setup an outlet for the scrollview and call:

```
self.scrollview.backgroundColor = NSColor.black
self.scrollview.contentView.backgroundColor = NSColor.black
```

...to no effect.

Additionally, I tried:

```
collectionView.superview?.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.black.cgColor
```

...but this doesn't work either.

Neither does:

```
self.view.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.black.cgColor
```

or:

```
self.view.window?.backgroundColor = NSColor.black
```

---

**Update:**

I have set the **background color** of the scroll view to red, and `drawsBackground` to `true` (both in IB and programmatically). The docs for `NSScrollView`'s `backgroundColor` property say:

> This color is used to paint areas inside the content view that aren’t
>   covered by the document view.

I have verified at runtime that the document view is indeed my collection view:

```
if scrollview.documentView is NSCollectionView {
        print("Document is collection")
}
```

However, no red is displayed and the area beyond the document (collection view) stays white.

---

**Update 2:** I fired the View Hierarchy Debugger, and it seems that the value of `drawsBackground` is false at runtime (I set it to `true` in **both** code **and** storyboard)!:

[image]

(the background color itself seems to be reflected, though)

Comment: Did you check for `nil`? I'm wondering whether `collectionView.superview?.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.black.cgColor` failed because it has no layer. OS X is not like iOS; NSViews do not necessarily have layers.

Comment: I added this code, and a breakpoint inside the if block is reached: `if let superLayer = collectionView.superview?.layer {
            superLayer.backgroundColor = NSColor.black.cgColor
        }`

Comment: I can paint the window's bottom chrome to black if I move the call `self.view.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.black.cgColor` to _after_ `self.view.wantsLayer = true`; However, the scroll view background remains white.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. In Interface Builder, select the CollectionView in the document outline.
2. In the Utilities window, show the Attributes inspector.
3. Set the desired color in the Primary color selector control.

Note: the Ray Wenderlich tutorial that you referenced sets the background color of the collection view programmatically. You'll either want to remove that line, or ensure that you are setting the same color that you chose in step 3 above.

[image]

Comment: Awesome! That did the trick. Thank you! I read the `NSCollectionView` docs now, but the explanation for the color properties is quite cryptic...

Answer (score 4):

for changing it programmatically in Swift 3 use e.g.:

```
collectionView.backgroundColors = [NSColor.black]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change `self.view.wantsLayer = true` in `self.collectionView.wantsLayer = true`